# $\operatorname{GL}_2$-type abelian varieties with full level-$p$ structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

For a prime $p$, does there exist a $\operatorname{GL}_2$-type abelian variety $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ having full level-$p$ structure? That is, $A[p]=(\mathbb{Z}/p)^d \oplus \mu_{p}^{d}$ as a $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$-module for $d$ the dimension.

For $p<7$, such $A$ exist — elliptic curves (concretely via [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org)). To begin, how about the case $p=7$?

Comment: I think the hyphen in "full level $p$-structure" was meant to be  moved, as "full level-$p$ structure", and have edited accordingly.  If that was wrong, I apologise!  Please feel free to move it back.

Comment: Does full level-$p$ structure mean that $A[p]$ has trivial Galois action? Because if so, then this only happens when $p=2$, as can be seen using the Weil pairing. (Even for elliptic curves)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, please let me know if the above version  still uncertain.

Comment: Not checked: Pick $N$ prime such that $p$ divides the numerator of $(N-1)/12$ and use https://math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/optimal.pdf Theorem B because the $\mathbf{Q}$-torsion subgroup of $J_0(N)$ is cyclic of order the numerator of $(N-1)/12$ by Mazur's Eisenstein paper.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Does having a suitable torsion subgroup guarantee the existence of full level $p$-structure? In general this is not true (for instance there are elliptic curves with a $7$- torsion, but no elliptic curve over the rationals has full level $7$-structure). The suggested scenario maybe special though.

Comment: According to Mazur's Eisenstein paper, Theorems 1 and 2 in the introduction, you should get for $p$ odd dividing the numerator of $(N-1)/12$ with $N$ prime, a subgroup $\mathbf{Z}/p \oplus \mu_p$ in $J_0(N)[p]$. The question is now if you can find a newform $f$ of level $N$ with rational coefficients such that the quotient $J_0(N) \to A_f$ is $1$-dimensional and thus has $A_f[p] = \mathbf{Z}/p \oplus \mu_p$ using Emerton's paper. (Edit: This doesn't work because elliptic curves have no $p$-torsion for $p > 7$.)

Comment: For a given prime $p$, one may hope for such an abelian variety of sufficiently large dimension. Mazur’s theorem alone does not seem to suffice, an additional idea maybe necessary.

Comment: One would need a $\operatorname{GL}_2$-type abelian variety $A_f$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ and $p$ *inert* in its endomorphism ring, with $\mathbf{Z}/p$ and $\mu_p$ contained in $A_f[p]$. The problem with what I write is that the prime $p$ is split.